# How to combine time for a second and minute in java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, datetime, java-8

I like to merge time for my project is there any other way ? for example for my yml listener both configure minute:1 and second: 18 so the time I  expect 78

my code below;

my yml below;

```
listener:
  info:
    hour: 0
    minute: 0
    second: 18
    milliSecond: 0
```

my Listener configuration below;

```
@Configuration
public class EventListenerConfiguration {

    @Value("${listener.info.hour}")
    private int listenerInfoHour;

    @Value("${listener.info.minute}")
    private int listenerInfoMinute;

    @Value("${listener.info.second}")
    private int listenerInfoSecond;

    @Value("${listener.info.milliSecond}")
    private int listenerInfoMilliSecond;

  
    public int getTotalMilliSecondTimeForInfoForSecond() {
        return listenerErrorSecond * 1000 + listenerErrorMilliSecond + listenerErrorMinute * 6000 + listenerErrorHour * 360_000;
    }

    public int getTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForMinute() {
        return listenerErrorMinute * 60_000 + listenerErrorMilliSecond + listenerErrorSecond * 6000 + listenerErrorHour * 360_000;
    }

    public int getTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForHour() {
        return listenerErrorHour * 3_600_000 + listenerErrorMilliSecond + listenerErrorMinute * 6000 + listenerErrorSecond * 360_000;
    }
```

my consume class below;

```
@Autowired
 EventListenerConfiguration eventListenerConfiguration;

private long lastReceivedMessage = System.currentTimeMillis();

@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${listenScheduled}", initialDelay = 1000)
    private void distanceBetweenLastReceivedMessageAndCurrentTime() {

        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastReceivedMessage;

        if (currentTime >= eventListenerConfiguration.getConcanteTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForSecondAndMinute()) {

            publishEvent("event info", EventSeverityStatus.ERROR, EventTypeStatus.ALERT, null);
```

so I have tried that "getConcanteTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForSecondAndMinute()" method but, unfortunately it does not concatenate second and minute.

```
    public int getConcanteTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForSecondAndMinute() {
        return getTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForSecond() + getTotalMilliSecondTimeForErrorForMinute();
    }
```

Comment: What do  you mean concatenate? Can you add an example?

Comment: listener:
  info:
    hour: 0
    minute: 0
    second: 18
     instead of  listener:
  info:
    hour: 0
    minute: 1
    second: 18    so the time will read  78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to calc it like this:

```
public int getTotalMilliSecondTime() {
    return listenerErrorMilliSecond + listenerErrorSecond * 1_000 + listenerErrorMinute * 60_000 + listenerErrorHour * 3_600_000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don’t do time math yourself. Use library methods. Your code will be clearer and more natural to read and will more easily convince your reader that it is correct. For an amount of time use the `Duration` class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    long totalMilliseconds = Duration.ofHours(0)
                                     .plusMinutes(1)
                                     .plusSeconds(18)
                                     .plusMillis(0)
                                     .toMillis();
    System.out.println("" + totalMilliseconds + " milliseconds");
```

Output from this example snippet is:

> 78000 milliseconds

I am assuming that the `listenerInfoHour` from your class goes instead of the `0` as argument of `ofHours()`. And similarly `.plusMillis(listenerInfoMilliSecond)`. I just put hardcoded numbers in the example for the sake of a minimal, simple and complete example.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.